# Best way to store nested static data(array) in Android?

Tags: android

So I have data, for example:

> 1 topic will be conducted in 2 class room with different subtopic each
>   hour from 9am-12pm.

It will look like below if in JSON format:

```
{
    "Mathematic": [
        {
            "time": [
                {
                    "startTime": "09.00",
                    "endTime": "10.00",
                    "class": [
                        {
                            "subtopic": "What is Calculus?",
                            "roomName": "Class A"
                        },
                        {
                            "subtopic": "Basic of Calculus",
                            "roomName": "Class B"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I put the json file in `assets` folder, I believe the JSON parser will take some time to parse it.

I also think about to put it in `arrays.xml`:

```
<array name="testArray">
    <item>first</item>
    <item>second</item>
    <item>
        <array name="testArrayNested">
            <item>
                first nested
            </item>
            <item>
                second nested
            </item>
        </array>
    </item>
    <item>fourth</item>
    <item>fifth</item>
</array>
```

I am not sure how to get the nested array, here is my code:

```
String [] test = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);
for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
    System.out.println("test: " + test[i]);
```

Output:

```
test: first
test: second
test:    first nested   second nested   
test: fourth
test: fifth
```

What is the best way to store nested static data?

Comment: An option would be splitting 3rd item by "  "/double space, so you can convert it from `String` to `String[]`

Comment: Yes that can be, but I hope there will be more efficient solution or the best practice.

Comment: If you want a super high speed solution, try storing your data in Java files as `static final`

Comment: Cant see so as to why it would take time with the json data. Your approach seems right with bundling the json in the assets and loading it from there into a json object.This would definitely load before the blink of an eye

Comment: Also I'm agree with @root

Comment: You can store it as json data and use JSON parser

Comment: @ABFORCE: sorry forgot to mention I don't want to put it in my Java files :D

Comment: @all: Actually I haven't tried to use JSON approach :D but I think because there will be 7 courses with 2 classroom each for each hour, so it will take some times to load with JSON.

Comment: Rest assured your dataset isn't even remotely large. go ahead with json

Comment: Thanks all! I have tried to parse the JSON, it only takes around 200ms to parse and load everything :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to meet your JSON, this type of strcutures will be needed.

```
class Lecture { //Mathematic
  String name;
  List<Timetable> timetables;
}

class Timetable { //time

  Time start;
  Time end;
  List<Lesson> classes;
}


class Lesson { //class
   ClassRoom room;
   Topic     topic;
}

class Topic { 
  String name;

}

class ClassRoom {
  String name;
}
```

But if you can change that json

I would suggest

```
class Subject {
    String topic;
}

class Lesson {
    Subject subject;
    String topic;
}

class Classroom {
    String name;
}

class ClassroomLesson {
    Lesson lesson;
    Classroom classroom;
    String hour;
}

class Schedule {
    List<ClassroomLesson> lessons = new ArrayList<>();
}


{
  "lessons": [
    {
      "lesson": {
        "subject": {
          "topic": "Mathematics"
        },
        "topic": "Lesson 1"
      },
      "classroom": {
        "name": "Classroom 1"
      },
      "hour": "09:00"
    },
    {
      "lesson": {
        "subject": {
          "topic": "Mathematics"
        },
        "topic": "Lesson 2"
      },
      "classroom": {
        "name": "Classroom 2"
      },
      "hour": "10:00"
    }
  ]
}
```